# How to correctly import Axios in vue 3 after creating new project with CLI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I created a new project using:

```
vue create hello-world
```

Generating a new project that includes the `HelloWorld.vue`, `app.vue`, `main.js` (etc ...) files.

Now I install Axios by following the docs [Npm vue-axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios):

```
npm install --save axios vue-axios
```

I import Axios in the `main.js` file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
```

And now I run into a problem that I don't understand. The `VueAxios` docs say you simply use it like so:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp(...)
app.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

But the way `app` is created in Vue 3 is different. I think this is where the problem comes from:

```js
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

So, how do I correctly import *axios*?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`createApp(App).mount('#app')` is effectively the same as:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
const app = Vue.createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')

// or
import { createApp } from 'vue'
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

So following Vue Axios's docs, just insert the line for `app.use()`:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(VueAxios, axios) // 
app.mount('#app')
```

You could also chain it like this:

```js
createApp(App).use(VueAxios, axios).mount('#app')
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vueaxios-in-vue-3-pkod8?file=/src/main.js:124-196)

Comment: @RizaKhan Technically, the original question has nothing to do with Composition API (and that tag should probably be removed), so I wouldn't update the demo here. In any case, I would simply import `axios` where needed (including in the Composition API) instead of using `vue-axios`.

Answer (score 30):

You could import only `axios` and define it as a [global property](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties) :

**Using a bundler (vue cli, vite or webpack ...):**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
const app = createApp(...)
app.config.globalProperties.axios=axios
```

then use it in any child component like:

**Option api** :

```
this.axios.get(...)
```

in **Composition api** I recommend to import it directly like :

```
import axios from 'axios'

const MyComponent = {
  setup() {
    //use axios here

   .... 
  }
}
```

or you use `useAxios` from the [vueuse](https://vueuse.org/) (vue composition utilities) :

```js
import { useAxios } from '@vueuse/integrations/useAxios'
...
 setup() {
   const { data, isFinished } = useAxios('/api/posts')
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me at VueJS 3.

```
npm i vue-axios

import { createApp } from "vue";
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(VueAxios)
app.use(axios)

app.mount("#app");


this.axios.get(api).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
})
```

Doc link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios