# How to call a custom global function using composition api | vue3

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuejs3, composition

In main.js, I set `axios` as a global function.

```js
//main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import axios from 'axios';
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$http = axios;
app.mount('#app');
```

The thing is how do I call this function in a component using composition api?

```html
<script>
export default {
  setup() {
   //how do I call the `axios` global function?
 };
</script>
```

Comment: You should be able to use it via `$http` but why don't you import it in the component?

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269587/how-to-correctly-import-axios-in-vue-3-after-creating-new-project-with-cli) pls

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, is it not possible to simply import `axios` in the components where it's needed? Using global properties is discouraged in Vue 3 with the composition API. With that said, this is still possible in a few ways:

#### Importing where needed

The ideal method, as I mentioned earlier, is simply to

```js
import axios from 'axios'
```

in components where it is needed.

#### Provide/inject

If, for whatever reason, you do need to provide Axios globally from your `app`, another way to do so is to use the [`Provide/Inject`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#using-provide) pattern.

In your `App.vue`:

```js
import { provide } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        provide('axios', axios);
    }
}
```

And in whatever components need it:

```js
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        const axios = inject('axios');
    }
}
```

#### `getCurrentInstance()` (discouraged)

Per [the Vue documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance),

> Usage of `getCurrentInstance` is strongly discouraged in application code. Do NOT use it as an escape hatch to get the equivalent of this in Composition API.

However, if you *really* want to maintain it as a global property, you can use it as follows:

```js
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

export default {
    setup() {
        const app = getCurrentInstance();
        const axios = app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$http;
```

Comment: All points are valid, however I have some concerns with defining `import axios` as the "ideal solution":  when it comes to modularization a core principle is to reduce internal coupling among them. This means that a module should not depend (thus include) directly another module but should rather ask the app to "provide" the single responsible for specific logic. 

Thus provide / inject solution looks more appropriate to me, except that if you want to implement it with TS you will end up coupling modules anyway  (consumer module needs to import the injection key anyway before injecting) 

Comment: Marco is correct... The idea behind `provide`/`inject` is to allow for dependency injection (DI) in Vue components. If you want every component in your Vue app to have access to the *same* instance of axios, but also have it have an agnostic custom name like `http`, so it can be switched out to another API identical/similar library, then you'd use `app.provide('http', axios)` in the OP's first code block. You can then proceed to use `const http = inject('http');` in any components in your application, and it'll just work. Now, if you want to change Axios, you only do so in one place.

Answer (score -6):

You can call it like so:

```js
this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1/api')
```

Comment: but `this` is undefined in setup function

Comment: this works in options api